# What should I do to get my boxes horizontally aligned?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried doing the `style="display: inline-block"` on each div but it doesn't work. Please help.

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```html
 <div class="hobby" style="display: inline-block">
        <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="coding.jpg" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Coding</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">This is my primary hobby. That's why I was able to create a lot of projects.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hobby" style="display: inline-block">
        <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="guitar.jpg" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Guitar</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">I love music. And one way I appreciate it is by playing guitar.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hobby" style="display: inline-block">
        <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="coding.jpg" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Mandarin</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">I learn Mandarin Chinese. I really like this language because of its intonation.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- hobby div -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap your code into parent div like this .

```
    <div style="display:flex">
      // your current code

   </div>
```

Comment: @Zeddrix Fabian can you please upvote this ans if this was fruitfull . Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Your current use of `style="display: inline-block"` seems to work for me.
Perhaps you should check the margins and padding on your elements to make sure there is enough room to fit them side-by-side.

```html
<div class="hobby" style="display: inline-block">
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:gray"></div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Coding</h3>
                <p class="card-text">This is my primary hobby..</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hobby" style="display: inline-block">
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:gray"></div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Guitar</h3>
                <p class="card-text">I love music.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hobby" style="display: inline-block">
    <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the style in a parent div.

```
<div class="parent-div>
    <div class="child-div>

    </div>
    <div class="child-div>

    </div>
    <div class="child-div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Try either:

```
.parent-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.child-div {
    width: 33%;
    height: 200 px;
}
```

Or:

```
.parent-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```